# One validation message for multiple fields

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm having a problem with jQuery validation and could use some suggestions.

Is there a way I can validate the three Phone Number fields in this form while only having one error message for the group? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Form

```
<form id="mForm" name="form">
<div class="field right">
  <label class="labelStd" id="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
  <input name="txtPhone1" type="text" maxlength="3" id="txtPhone1" class="small-phone" name="txtPhone1" Onchange="Tab(this, 'txtPhone2');" />
  <input name="txtPhone2" type="text" maxlength="3" id="txtPhone2" class="small-phone" name="txtPhone2" Onchange="Tab(this, 'txtPhone3');" />
  <input name="txtPhone3" type="text" maxlength="4" id="txtPhone3" class="small-phone" name="txtPhone3" />
</div>

<button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="button-black right">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Script (with jquery validate)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mForm").validate({

onfocusout:false,
focuseInvalid:false,
onkeyup:false,

rules: {

    txtPhone1:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 3
        },
    txtPhone2:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 3
        },
    txtPhone3:{
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4
        }
    },

messages: {

    txtPhone1: "Your phone number is required.",
    txtPhone2: "Your phone number is required.",
    txtPhone3: "Your phone number is required."
}


  });

  $("#mForm").submit(function(){

if($(this).valid()){

form.submit();

}

else{ }

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)...

> Specify grouping of error messages. A group consists of an arbitrary
>   group name as the key and a space separated list of element names as
>   the value. Use errorPlacement to control where the group message is
>   placed.

```
groups:  {
    someArbitraryName: "txtPhone1 txtPhone2 txtPhone3"
}
```

**Generic Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/3RFsa/**

**Sidenote**:

Regarding your `submit` handler...

```
$("#mForm").submit(function(){
    if($(this).valid()){
        form.submit();
    }
...
```

It's totally superfluous and unnecessary, so I would remove it entirely.  By default, the plugin will automatically submit the form only *if/when it's valid*.  If you'd like to do something else in addition to the `submit()`, you can use the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  If you need to do something when the form fails validation, use the plugin's `invalidHandler` callback function.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. but it still displays the label after the first input which splits the layout. Is there an easy way to place the error label after the last input of the group?

Comment: @jaruesink, as per the documentation quoted in my answer, you would need to tweak the placement using the `errorPlacement` callback function.  The documentation for its usage is on the same page as the `groups` option.