# Pass value to the custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I want to customize a attribute. Say

```
public class IdExistAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                                  ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string id= value.ToString();
        if(ListOfId.Contains(id))
        {
           return new ValidationResult("Id is already existing");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
     }
 }
```

The question is that `ListOfId` is from service, I can't consume the service inside the attribute. So how to pass it from outside?

I want to use the attribute as

```
private string _id;
[IdExist]
public string Id
{
  get{return _id;}
  set{_id=value;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ValidationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) provide access to the registered dependency injection container via `GetService`.

Quoting [Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/injecting-services-into-validationattributes-in-asp-net-core/):

> As you can see, you are provided a ValidationContext as part of the method call. The context object contains a number of properties related to the object currently being validated, and also this handy number:
>
> public object GetService(Type serviceType);

So you can use `ValidationContext` like so:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var service = (IExternalService) validationContext
                         .GetService(typeof(IExternalService));
    // use service
}
```

Comment: Can we just pass the list value to attribute? Because I can get the value in my model class. I don't have  something like `IExternalService`

Comment: You can only pass compile-time values into an attribute [declaration], unfortunately. The only other option is to use a `static` value on `IdExistAttribute ` and then set that before the attribute is used. I'd recommend creating a service for this, if at all possible.

Comment: The drawback is if the property changed, I have to call the service to get the same value again. It has the performance issue. Maybe I shouldn't use the attribute? Maybe there is another way for the validation?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848134/custom-validation-based-on-other-value