# ASP.Net Core MVC - Show custom validation error in summary only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom ValidationAttribute partially based on this SO answer [Group validation messages for multiple properties together into one message asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725417/group-validation-messages-for-multiple-properties-together-into-one-message-asp)

I would like to show the custom error in the following only

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

At the moment it shows both on the field and summary.

My code as follows:

ValidationAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class GroupTotalAttribute : ValidationAttribute//, IClientModelValidator
{
    private string[] _serverSideProperties;
    private int _total;

    public GroupTotalAttribute(int total, params string[] serverSideProperties)
    {
        _serverSideProperties = serverSideProperties;
        _total = total;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_serverSideProperties == null || _serverSideProperties.Length < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int sumOfInputs = 0;

        foreach (var input in _serverSideProperties)
        {
            var propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(input);
            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property {0}", input));
            }

            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (propertyValue is int)
            {
                sumOfInputs += int.Parse(propertyValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (sumOfInputs == _total)
        {
            return null;

        }

        return new ValidationResult(string.Format("doesnt add up to {0}", _total));
        //return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class GroupValidationExampleViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0,5)]
    [GroupTotal(5, "ValueOne", "ValueTwo", "ValueThree", "ValueFour", "ValueFive")]
    public int ValueOne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueTwo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueThree { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFive { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueOne" class="small mb-1">Value One</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueOne" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueOne" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueTwo" class="small mb-1">Value Two</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueTwo" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueTwo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueThree" class="small mb-1">Value Three</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueThree" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueThree" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueFour" class="small mb-1">Value Four</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueFour" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueFour" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueFive" class="small mb-1">Value Five</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueFive" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueFive" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented class level validation instead.

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
public class GroupValidationExampleViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    private const int _total = 18;

    [Required]
    [Range(0,5)]
    //[GroupTotal(5, "ValueOne", "ValueTwo", "ValueThree", "ValueFour", "ValueFive")]
    public int ValueOne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueTwo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueThree { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFive { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if ((ValueOne + ValueTwo + ValueThree + ValueFour + ValueFive) != _total)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("group total error model only");
        }
    }
}
```

This displays the error in asp-validation-summary="All" field only

Answer (score 0):

Define a nullable property specifically for custom validation.

```
public class GroupValidationExampleViewModel
{
    [GroupTotal(5, "ValueOne", "ValueTwo", "ValueThree", "ValueFour", "ValueFive")]
    public int? Sum { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueOne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueTwo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueThree { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFour { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int ValueFive { get; set; }
}
```

Use asp-validation-for="Sum" to show the validation message of your custom validation

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span asp-validation-for="Sum" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueOne" class="small mb-1">Value One</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueOne" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueOne" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueTwo" class="small mb-1">Value Two</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueTwo" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueTwo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueThree" class="small mb-1">Value Three</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueThree" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueThree" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueFour" class="small mb-1">Value Four</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueFour" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueFour" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label asp-for="ValueFive" class="small mb-1">Value Five</label>
        <input asp-for="ValueFive" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValueFive" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: I want to keep the field validation where the message is related to just that field. But have the message for the group validation only appear in the summary field.

Comment: @Barnsley Sorry, I misunderstood at first. asp-validation-summary will always render a summary of form validation error messages, so  I think you can define an extra property in your viewmodel and put the group validation on it ,then you can separate the error messages. I have edited my post.

Comment: thanks for help and that did work but i didnt like the idea of having to create redundant fields for the requirement of serving validation messages. I opted instead for class level validation, IValidatableObject. These messages only appeared in the summary.